# Berlin 1923 & 1925 Address Book Abbreviations "I", "E", "Kgst" and "Mb"

Tags: meaning, abbreviation, address

I am doing genealogical research in Berlin address books. There are a couple of abbreviations that I cannot find by searching German dictionaries and German abbreviation reference websites. I was hoping someone here may know what these Address book abbreviations mean. If anyone has a resource that explains address book and phone book abbreviations, I would be forever grateful.

1. I cannot find the meaning for "I" after an address. Is it perhaps a floor number or apartment number?

Example: Maschke, A., u. Co., Schuhwaren en gros, NO 55, Winsstr. Nr. 63 I.  T. Kgst, 2616.

Example: Aron Maschke Kaufmann NO 55, Winstrasse 64 I

2. I searched for "Kgst" and the only thing I found was [Kommunale Gemeinschaftsstelle](https://www.kgst.de/ueber-uns) Does this make sense? Maschke was self-employed so perhaps it means he was a member of this group?

Example: Maschke, A., u. Co., Schuhwaren en gros, NO 55, Winsstr. Nr. 63 I.  T. Kgst, 2616.

3. I keep seeing "E" is written in block font while the majority of the books are in Gothic font. It is usually at the end of an entry. Does it perhaps indicate a business owner?

Example: Maschke, Georg. Schuhwrhdlg., NW 87, Wiclefstrasse 42. T. Mb  4843. E.

4. I also cannot find the meaning of "Mb".

Example: Maschke, Georg. Schuhwrhdlg., NW 87, Wiclefstrasse 42. T. Mb  4843. E.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not sure how you access these address books, but if you look at [urn:nbn:de:kobv:109-1-3497746](https://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:kobv:109-1-3497746), you find answers to two of your questions on page 53 of the scan ("Zur Handhabung"). In short, (1) the roman numeral (I, II, etc) gives the floor number and (3) the *E* at the end stands for "Eigentümer" (owner). According to the explanation, this is used for the owner of a house, though, not the owner of a business.

If you compare (2) and (4), *Kgst.* and *Mb.* appear at exactly the same spot. And since the *T* stands for "Telefonnummer", I would presume that what follows is, well, the phone number. And if it's the phone number, I would guess that *Kgst.*, *Mb.* etc stand for different "phone districts" within the city (Daniel Hoffmann suggests Königstwusterhausen and Moabit, which sounds plausible). This seems sensible given how phone calls were initiated in the 1920s (ie, you talked to the operator in charge of your own "phone district" and told him which "phone district" you want to be connected to, then you were transfered to the operator of the target district, gave him the phone number, and then he transfered you to the person you wanted to talk to).

*Update:* On p 57 of said scan, at the top it says "T = Telephon, Amt u. Nr.", which confirms the above suspicion: The *T* is followed by the "Amt" (the office in charge) and then the actual number.

*Update II:* Inspired by another answer, I think I've now found some sources for these abbreviations. In the *Amtliches Fernsprechbuch für Berlin* - unfortunately, the closest in time I could find is from 1934 - there is a "Verzeichnis der Fernsprechämter und Vermittlungsstellen des Ortsnetzes Berlin". See [urn:nbn:de:kobv:109-1-15377045](https://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:kobv:109-1-15377045), page 12 of the scan ([non-stable direct link](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/15849352_1934/12/LOG_0018/)): According to this list, *Kgst.* stands for the Vermittlungsstelle ("transfer office") **Königstadt**. This list does not contain *Mb.*, though (but as I said it's from a decade later). In the *Adressbuch der deutschen Gummi-, Asbest- und Celluloid-Industrie* of 1920 I found a list of Fernsprechämter that contains both *Kgst.* (= Königstadt) and *Mb.* (= **Moabit**). See [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=w8Pvsh7ddGYC&q=kgst%20k%C3%B6nigstadt&dq=kgst%20k%C3%B6nigstadt&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCsuvs_bLmAhUNKKwKHWzaBsIQ6AEwAnoECAMQAg) (snippet view only):

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the same link then: https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/readingmode/34115495_1923/53/LOG_0011/ ? (this is edition 1923, page 53 explaining how to use this address book) [I thought I found sth different, just realized that same page loads)

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's from the very address book that this question is apparently concerned with.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Yes this all makes sense. They were living in Konigstadt at the time. Would "I" indicate the ground floor or first floor? For example, I have Winsstr. 64 and 64 I. Are those the same floor or different floors? I assume they are both the same floor

Comment: @KatV In Germany, the ground floor is not the first floor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey#Numbering), and as I understand the usage notes in the address book, they would denote the ground floor as "Erdg." (Erdgeschoss). Therefore, I assume that the absence of any specfication of the floor either means that the entry refers to the building as a whole or that the floor was unknown.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer:

**Kgst** is abbreviated for *Königsstadt*, *Königsviertel* or *Georgenvorstadt* a district of Berlin, see [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nigsstadt).

For a list of historical Berlin districts, see either explanation of district map in the same article, or [Brockhaus 1894-1896](https://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=122107). In the [map of Berlin](https://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/hiresfaksimile_5179988.jpeg) 
*Wiensstraße* (*ie* instead of *i* from your excerpt) is listed in the respective region in quadrants H2/H3.

Answer (score 8):

As already communicated by others, e.g. the abbreviations `I, II or III` designate the floor, `T.` a telecommunications connection (*Telefonanschluss*) and `E` an owner.

The [Berlin Address Book 1923](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/readingmode/34115495_1923/4556/) contains a list of telephone exchange offices on page 4556 and is supplemented here as a source reference.

[image]

The telephone office 2 (*Fernsprechamt 2*) for Moabit and Hansa was located in Lübecker Straße 1. As you can see in [Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Wiclefstra%C3%9Fe+42,+10551+Berlin/@52.5307925,13.3285986,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47a8516d26bc4be7:0xd96474a6bee65587!8m2!3d52.5307893!4d13.3307873), **Wiclefstraße 42** (from your question) is located in [Berlin-Moabit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin-Moabit) nearby this historical office. Therefore `Mb` correctly stands for `Moabit`.

There also the offices `Königstadt` and `Alexander` are listed under the telephone office 7 (*Fernsprechamt 7*), which were accommodated together in the Palisadenstraße 90 starting from 15 August 1912. As you can see in [Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Winsstra%C3%9Fe+63,+10405+Berlin/@52.5301171,13.40571,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47a84e0453e895b5:0xc5154e7c14f9340f!8m2!3d52.53313!4d13.424), **Winsstraße 63** (from your question) is located in the northeast of the Berlin center nearby this office. Therefore and derived from the spatial and technical context `Kgst` correctly stands for `Königstadt`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Mb is the abbreviation for the Moabit telephone exchange, Kgst stands for the Königstadt telephone exchange. See attached picture from the 1932 Berlin telephone directory.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I dont know the answer, but I have a hint, you might follow. Kgst. might be Königstwusterhausen and Mb Moabit. Both are regions wihin Berlin. This can be evaluated by having a look on the map.

Comment: Also the Adress given (Wiclefstraße) seems to be in Moabit.

Comment: Königs Wusterhausen (not "Königst-") is a town in Brandenburg, not a part of Berlin. And abbreviating it with "Kgst" (rather than something like "KW" or "Kwh" or "Kgwh") would be very odd.

Comment: I lived there in my high school times and we usually call it KW.