# How do I specify the floor number in the address for deliveries?

Tags: address

So, it appears Germany doesn't believe in apartment numbers, so couriers must use my surname to locate my apartment.
Some new buildings have the floor number written near the intercom buttons, but my building does not (a new building from late 2019).
The couriers always ask me for the floor number (at least, that is what I guess they ask) over the intercom.
I'm not judging, there must be a thousand year old reason for this.

What do I need to state in my address so the couriers would not have to deal with my very poor german?
`5 Etage`? `5 Stock`? `5 Et.` ?

Comment: If you have an elevator - what is written there?

Comment: @userunknown The elevator button on my floor shows the digit 5.

Comment: A *currier* is someone who curries (grooms) and cleans horses in a stable. Someone who carries parcels and delivers them is a *carrier*. You used three time the wrong word. I corrected this in your question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast It was a spelling mistake, the word should have been `courier` and not your correction: `carrier`

Comment: @MosheGottlieb well then, don't hesitate to edit the question to better match your intention! This change would not invalidate any answers, and is thus acceptable.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure you ever want the courier to know that you live on the fifth floor by looking at your parcel. If there are two parcels for your building, expect them to ring the other door first and give them both.

Comment: @SimonRichter LOL, that is so true 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please see [mtwde's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58606/30455) to see how to specify this in an address line

You do not use the cardinal numbers but the ordinal numbers, i.e.

> 5. Etage (fünfte Etage)
>   5. Stock (fünfter Stock)

The dot is important. Or you could reverse the order

> Etage 5 (Etage fünf)
>   <strike>Stock 5</strike> (sounds unusual)

As mentioned in the comments by [Carsten S](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/3237/carsten-s) , you can also write

> 5.Obergeschoss  or
>   5. OG

Please note that Germans start counting floor levels at 0. The ground-floor would be level 0, although nobody calls it that way. It is called *Erdgeschoss*. The floor above is *der 1. Stock*, unlike in the US where it would be the 2nd floor.

Comment: Thank your for this!  Vielen Dank!

Comment: UK is the same as Germany.

Comment: I would usually write "5. OG" (Obergeschoss)

Comment: Note that, unlike "5. Etage" or "5. Stock", using "5. Obergeschoss" or "5. OG" has the added advantage that it makes unmistakably clear that we are talking about the fifth floor *above ground*, removing any potential confusion about regional / cultural differences, especially considering that couriers are often immigrants who might come from a culture that counts floors differently.

Comment: Also (just for completeness sake), the first level below ground would usually be called "1. UG" (erstes Untergeschoss). So you have 1. UG < EG < 1. OG, which has a nice symmetry to it.

Comment: In Berlin where the Wilhelminian apartment buildings frequently have [multiple wings](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterhaus#/media/Datei:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-1984-0926-303,_Berlin,_Schliemannstra%C3%9Fe_18,_Hinterhof.jpg)  we would sometimes write "Q 2. OG r", indicating "Quergebäude 2. Obergeschoß rechts" (using the old spelling for authenticity ;-) ). To give you an idea of the building density, [here](https://goo.gl/maps/Nmf7eaHvP4VSJGFd7) is a google view.

Answer (score 10):

@infinitezero tells you what to write, but not where and how to write it. As with a lot of things in Germany, there is a national standard for this. In this case it is [DIN 5008](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008).

DIN 5008 says, that the apartment or floor number is written after the street + house number and is separated by two dashes (//). <sup>[1](http://buerojob-blog.de/2012/11/08/din-5008-zustellvermerke-wohnungapartment-und-etagestockwerk/)</sup> <sup>[2](https://www.wirtschaftsdeutsch.de/lehrmaterialien/korrespondenz-anschriftfeld.pdf)</sup>

So if you want to add the floor or apartment number to the address you write:

> Straße Hausnummer // x. Etage

The whole address could then look like this

```
Herr
Max Mustermann
Musterstraße 123 // 6. Etage
12345 Musterstadt
```

The expression 6. Etage, as written in the other answer, can be replaced by 6. Stock. Sometimes the floor number is written in Roman numerals ("// VI" in this case), but this is no longer a standard and the floor number [should be written out](http://buerojob-blog.de/2012/11/08/din-5008-zustellvermerke-wohnungapartment-und-etagestockwerk/).

**EDIT:**

**Fun Fact** (as OP is from Berlin)

In this old (1923) [adress book from Berlin](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/34115495_1923/53/LOG_0011/) a lot of adresses include the floor number in Roman numerals. Something you won't see anymore today (found [via this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/berlin-1923-1925-address-book-abbreviations-i-e-kgst-and-mb/55657#answer-55654))

---

@Polygnome made a good point, so I want to quote his comment:

> While this may be the official DIN, I suppose not many people actually know that DIN and mailman regularly manage to deliver to non-standard addresses ;)

Comment: Thanks! Will start using the standard form

Comment: While this may be the official DIN, I suppose not many people actually know that DIN and mailman regularly manage to deliver to non-standard addresses ;) Nice answer nonetheless.

Comment: I used to put my flat number just below the address line and before the zip code. Also seemed to work.

Comment: _Of course_ there's a DIN for it!

Answer (score 5):

infinitezero already has given the [correct answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58600/how-do-i-specify-the-floor-number-in-the-address-for-deliveries/58601#58601). I just wanted to add something about apartment numbers, but it's too long for a comment, so I hope it's ok to post it as an answer (although it isn't really an answer to your question).

I can't speak for Germany because I live in Austria, but here in Austria we "believe" in apartment numbers too, and I am very convinced, that German people also do. But when a courier wants to bring you a parcel, he has to take the elevator to reach your floor, and there he needs to know which button to press. Or he walks up the stairs, and then he also needs to know the level where your apartment is. Otherwise he had to search in every floor for an apartment with your apartment number, and couries don't have the time for such searches. So, when he rings you at the intercom, he wants to know two things:

1. Are you at home? (This will be answered automatically when you pick up)
2. Which floor? (This is the only thing you have to say)

There are some buildings, where the floor number is included in the apartment number. This is standard in hotels. (Room 101 to 126 are in 1st floor, 201 to 226 in 2nd floor etc., which also means, that there are no rooms with numbers from 127 to 200.) In bigger residential buildings you can find the hotel system as just described, but smaller ones (with less than 50 or 100 apartments) most often only use consecutive numbers. And those consecutive numbers don't give a hint to the floor number. I am living now in an apartment that has the number 15 and is in the the 3rd floor. 2 years ago I lived in another building and I also had apartment 15 over there, but there it was in the 4th floor.

Here in Austria (but not in Germany, as I have learned) there is also an additional number in bigger residential buildings which is called "Stiege" ("stair" or "staircase") that you have to tell when the courier rings you. This is if the building has more than one staircases to reach different apartments. The house has just one house-number, but you need to know which staircase to take. (For details read [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34440/wie-nennt-man-in-deutschland-die-stiege-als-bestandteil-einer-adresse), but it is in German.)

Comment: Thank you for this information! Evidently, I'm no expert in German addressing... In my neighborhood (Friedrichshain, Berlin) there aren't any apartment numbers - or at least, I haven't seen any.  Hotels around me (and all over the world) employ the floor number prefix for apartment/room numbers (i.e. 603 is the 3rd room/apartment in the 6th floor).

Comment: In my apartment in Wilmersdorf we have apartment numbers, but it is literally the only building I have ever seen in Berlin which has them.

Comment: I've seen places where you had to know which staircase to take in Germany, too, usually big corporate or government buildings. But I don't know if there is a standard way to communicate this or if it's just a free style Adresszusatz.

Comment: When we had lectures in the university hospital Aachen, "adresses" had the form "A3 E6 R16", meaning "take elevator A3 to the sixth floor and then good luck finding room 16". For mail, you would put them in a separate row between name and real address.

Comment: German here with the experience that apartment numbers are rarely a thing in everyday life. They are almost never written at the apartment door. They *may* exist in the rental contract and in consequence also in the contract with electricity, IP/phone suppliers and big fuse box. But even for these descriptions like "2. OG links" are common in my experience. (Student dorms often have them, though)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: Germany is different from Austria in even more ways than I've thought. When you live in such a building and when there are no numbers at the door: How can I find your apartment when I reached the right floor?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: several possibilities. a) for the parcel delivery as per question, the customary/polite way where I've been was always to go down and meet the parcel guy at the front door (as long as the recipient is physically able to take the parcel to their apartment). b) when acquantances or the plumber come, say e.g. "2. OG last door to the right" + maybe go to open the door and meet them. c) as the one to visit, read the name labels at all doors.

Comment: ... This also applies when you don't know the floor: many houses have at most 3 flats going off one staircase of which all names are plain in sight from the stairs. You can read the names as you wind up your way. And, as acquaintance possibly speed this up by knowing that small kid's shoes should or should not be in front of that door :-) Oh, and we have tons of discussions about data privacy, but name tags at the door bell are not a particular concern. One can ask to not have one's name at the door bell, though, and whether or not one puts a name to the flat door is up to the inhabitants.

Comment: Same here. I have been living in Graz for all my life, and never really used apartment numbers. But this is mostly due to the fact it always were buildings where all doors are directly opening to the staircase. And couriers or visitors will just walk up until they find the one open door (possibly with me waiting). So this is not totally universal.